# Why do two images pop up with Fancybox 1.3.4?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am working on a section for a client that has two images displaying in the Fancybox 1.3.4 display here: http://corecubed.com/portfolio/project/atlanta-home-care-partners-alzheimers-whisperer174-brochure

When you click on the image, it pops to not just one image but two and they have different appearances as well. The topmost image has a different close button and also has the option to enlarge to full screen.

I didn't build this so I am not exactly sure what is happening here and could use some help to trouble shoot it.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="featured featured1">
    <a class="preloading" href="http://corecubed.com/images/uploads/AHCP_AlzWhisperer_Broc_Portfolio_XL.jpg"><img src="http://corecubed.com/images/uploads/AHCP_AlzWhisperer_Broc_Portfolio_Medium.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div><!-- end .featured -->
```

Here is the jQuery for that part:

```
jQuery(".preloading").fancybox({
'showTitle'     : false,
'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
'scrolling'         : 'no'
});
```

Any help in resolving this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're attaching PrettyPhoto and Fancybox lightboxes to the same elements.

First of all you're attaching FancyBox to all `.preloading` elements on lines 38-44:

```
jQuery(".preloading").fancybox({
    'showTitle' : false,
    'transitionIn' : 'fade',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'scrolling' : 'no'
});
```

Then, on line 21 of `custom.js` you're calling this:

```
my_lightbox("a[rel^='prettyPhoto'], a[rel^='lightbox']",true);
```

Which initialises PrettyPhoto on all matched elements in the selector argument (lines 1528-1529 of `custom.js`):

```
jQuery($elements).prettyPhoto({ /* ... */ });
```

The solution is to pick one lightbox plugin and stick to it or at least stop targeting the same image with both.

Try removing the `jQuery(".preloading").fancybox({ /* ... */ )};` code and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of this:

```
jQuery("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'titleFormat'           : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
}
```

Somehow you are adding automatically the grouping also, you cant' see in in source code but you can if you are using an element inspector.